# Split a table row into multiple rows if length is exceeded

Tags: javascript, css, css-tables

I have a PHP script which returns a long row. Using that I have made a snippet here - http://jsfiddle.net/MLZEb/6/

Can you help me break the row into multiple rows rather than having a horizontal scrollbar (http://jsfiddle.net/MLZEb/)?

Currently I am using word-wrap, which makes it unreadable.

```
td
{
word-wrap: break-word;
}
table
{
width:100%;
table-layout:fixed;
}
```

[image: Snapshot of what I'm looking for]

Comment: Could you make a quick scribble how it should look like?

Comment: I can't imagine how that should look like...

Comment: Think of it like two rows....Snapshot attached of what I want. Basically the first row reaches the end of the screen, and then creates a new row.

Comment: And how do you want to split it, using css, php, jquery, ...? I will be amazed if somebody posts a css-only solution.

Comment: you have two options, change the markup or use some Javascript

Comment: Css or php, either works fine. Not so familiar with jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semantically speaking, breaking up your row into multiple isn't a great choice because your columns won't match up with their headers anymore.  That doesn't mean you're stuck with a ghastly, unresponsive table.

Making a table fit within a narrow (mobile) device is quite easy and requires minimal markup changes:

http://jsfiddle.net/MLZEb/9/

```
tbody, tr, th, td { display: block }
thead { display: none }
td:before {
    content: attr(data-label);
    display: inline-block;
    width: 6em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

td:first-child {
    background: #CCC;
}
```

You'll need to add the `data-label` attribute to your `td`s for this to work:

```
<td data-label="ID">49251</td>
```

If you want to fill out more horizontally for wider viewports, you could employ the use of floats on some of the columns (note that a few cells have been rearranged so that they lay out nicer):

http://jsfiddle.net/MLZEb/10/

```
table, tbody, tr, th, td { display: block; border: none }
thead { display: none }
td:before {
    content: attr(data-label);
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

td.attrib { /* add this class to any cell that should appear on the left */
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 15em;
}
```

Comment: I was actually thinking of something similar....If table exceeds a certain length, make it like this. Else keep it to the default format.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can just ignore the rows altogether and have the table cells floating:

```
table { width: 400px; }
td
{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MLZEb/8/).

Comment: I get what you attempted, but that's worse than the horizontal scroll-bar in the actual page. Sorry.

Comment: Fair enough, but I think you'll have to use JavaScript and split the cells into new rows on the fly.

Comment: Ya,but sadly I have no idea about splitting it on the fly with java-script? For now, I will leave it like this, and add this feature later.

Comment: Since you didn't tag with JavaScript I assume you're not interested in such a solution. If you'll change your mind give it a try yourself and if stuck feel free to bump me here again. :)